# How do you bypass the Microsoft Online "Stay signed in" when doing WS-Federated login?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, office365, adfs, ws-federation

I am doing logins to Microsoft Sharepoint Online through an AD-Sycned ADFS using SAML1.1 and WS-federation.

I obtain a saml assertion first from ADFS. Then I submit a web request:

HTTP POST: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`

Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

With Form:

`wa` = `wsignin1.0`

`wctx` = my web ctx

`wresult` = my saml assertion

Response: I clearly was able to log in, but instead of getting a page where I can obtain the token from, I get this page: [image]

I found this page but my admins won't let me make the change it suggests which is company wide: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/09/19/fewer-login-prompts-the-new-keep-me-signed-in-experience-for-azure-ad-is-in-preview/

How can I bypass this response during ADFS ws federated login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do what everyone else does in this situation when using Microsoft's terribly undocumented api's is to use fiddler to find out what to do.

Basically I turned on Fiddler, enabled HTTPS decryption support, then ran a login from an incognito browser window.

This shows me what form Post to emulate.

The following java code is what I came up with as a result, and it works:

```
    Map configMap = getRememberMePageConfigMap(wsfedRes);
    if (configMap != null) {
      String sFT = (String) configMap.get("sFT");
      String sFTName = (String) configMap.get("sFTName");
      String ctx = (String) configMap.get("sCtx");
      if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sFT) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(sFTName) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(ctx)) {
        LOG.info("Found the \"Remember Me\" page when we requested ws-federated auth token. Bypassing it.");
        HttpPost rememberMePost = new HttpPost(MICROSOFT_ONLINE_LOGIN_KMSI_URL);
        List<NameValuePair> wsFedFormParams = new ArrayList<>(3);
        wsFedFormParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(sFTName, sFT));
        wsFedFormParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctx", ctx));
        wsFedFormParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LoginOptions", "0"));
        rememberMePost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        rememberMePost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        rememberMePost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(wsFedFormParams));
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(rememberMePost)) {
          String content = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
          if (diagnosticMode) {
            LOG.info("After posting to {} to bypass the \"Remember me\" page, got statusCode={}, response={}",
                MICROSOFT_ONLINE_LOGIN_KMSI_URL, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), content);
          }
          return content;
        }
      }
    }
```

Where getRememberMePageConfigMap is

```
Map getRememberMePageConfigMap(String wsfedRes) throws IOException {
    String lines[] = wsfedRes.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
      if (line.startsWith("$Config=")) {
        String jsonToParse = line.substring("$Config=".length());
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonToParse, Map.class);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

This extra request correctly bypasses the form.